# SAS reading a file in long format

Tags: sas, linear-regression

I have a file in long format, like so:

```
name weight month cal

bob 80 01 5000

ben 70 01 4989

mary 60 01 3000

bob 81 02 4999

ben 68 02 6000

mary 57 02 2800

...
```

I would like to create N linear regressions of weight over cal: one for each of the months.
I know how to read the data into a dataset and how to fit a regression model.

I am not sure how I do this in a loop for the N months...

Any pointers?

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to provide some code here.  Are you talking about how to run `proc logistic` or similar N times?  What is the relevance of "long format", which you thought important enough to make your title entirely that, but doesn't seem relevant to your question.

Comment: I have N months. For each month I have information about bob, ben and mary. I would like to fit a linear regression model each of the months. If I had only 3 months it would have been simple - I would create 3 new datasets; one for each month and then fit the model for each of the datasets (I know how to do that). As I have many months, I need to find a way to do it iteratively somehow and keep the model results in some output... with that I struggle (very new to SAS). 10X

Comment: Maybe I could somehow utilize the 'group by' option to achieve this? https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000761932.htm

Comment: Code, as in SAS code.  Edit the original question with what you have figured out so far.  Put in your `proc logistic` or `proc glm` or `proc surveyreg` or whatever code that works for 1 month.  How you're doing this determines the correct answer.