# several regressions on a single dataset in SAS

Tags: sas, linear-regression

I have a dataset of the following format:
a table of M rows and 2K columns.
My columns are pairs of variables: X_i, Y_i and the rows are observations.

I would like to perform many linear regressions: one for each pair of columns (Y_i ~ X_i)
and obtain the results.

I know how to access specific columns using arrays, like so:

```
data Xs_Ys_data (drop=i);
array Xs[60] X1-X60;
array Ys[60] Y1-Y60;
```

I also know how to fit a single linear regression model, like so:

```
proc reg data=some_data;
model y = x;
output out=out_lin_reg;
run;
```

And I am familiar with the concept of loops:

```
do i=1 to 60;
Xs[i] .......;
end;
```

How do I combine these three to get what I need?

Thanks!

P.S - I asked a similar question on a different format here:

[SAS reading a file in long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589223/sas-reading-a-file-in-long-format)

---

Update:

I have managed to create the regressions using a macro like so:

```
 %macro mylogit();
     %do i = 1 %to 60;
      proc reg data=Xs_Ys_data;
          model Y&i = X&i;
      run;
 %end;
 %mend;

 %mylogit()
```

Now I am not sure how to export the results into a single table...

Comment: The answer is that you don't.  Perform the regression in long format.  The other option is to pull the variables into a macro string, but that is harder to do and much harder on your computer's resources in any event.

Comment: Hi Joe, It seems to work with the macro. Having done this, is there a simple way to keep the parameter estimates in a single table? Thanks!

Comment: Again, by doing it properly.  That macro will run 60 regressions, which will take a long time AND create 60 tables that you then have to append together.  Construct it in long format (you indicate you already have this) and use BY statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your macro:

```
  proc reg data=Xs_Ys_data;
      model Y&i = X&i;
  run;
```

So instead create:

```
data x_y_Data;
set xs_yx_data;
array xs x1-x60;
array yx y1-y60;
do iter = 1 to dim(xs);
x=xs[iter];
y=ys[iter];
output;
end;
run;

proc reg data=X_Y_data;
    by iter;
    model Y = X;
run;
```

And then add an output statement however you normally would to get your resulting dataset.  Now you get 1 output table with all 60 iterations (still 60 printed outputs), and if you want to create one printed output you can construct that from the output dataset.

Comment: I apologize for the stupid questions. I am really new to SAS and I work by putting together pieces of information I find on the net... Time is not really an issue here, so I don't have to worry about this. I am not sure how to add an output statement such that I'll have all in a table (seems like you hint this is possible). Also, I am not sure why the use of the macro is not good (as it seems to work and calculate the models - just not to print them all to one place...) Thanks!!!

Comment: The macro is just an overly complicated way to do it, when the above does the same thing.  Look up the documentation on PROC REG, it explains how to add an output statement.